# Loading table into R from SQL Server database

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbplyr

I get the following error when I try to load a table from a SQL Server in an Azure VM. I know the connection is successful, but I'm unable to get my syntax correct for the tables I want to load into R environment.

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Harris_11292021.dbo.Applicant'.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> 'SELECT *
> FROM "Harris_11292021"."dbo.Applicant" AS "q14"
> WHERE (0 = 1)'

I'm trying to load the table `Applicant`. Is the issue that the connection is to `applied_systems` and there is a further database and schema level below that before you get to table?

I tried to deal with that using in_schema command, but think I have implemented it wrong.

```
library(odbc)
library(tidyverse)

# Data connection to database --------------------------------------
con_applied <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "applied_systems", timeout = 10)

# Load table -------------------------------------------------------------
policy_master <- tbl(con_applied, in_schema("Harris_11292021", "dbo.Applicant"))
```

Here is a screenshot of the connection:

[image: schema]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Harris_1129021` is the database, `dbo` is the schema, and `Applicant` is the table name.  The Database is typically specified in the connection string or DSN.  So should probably be `in_schema("dbo", "Applicant")`.  But `dbo` is a kind of default schema, so you don't really need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks David.  So do I put the Harris_1129021 database name in the dbConnect command?  I tried that, but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.  Add database name in the dbConnect statement.

```
# Data connection to database backup --------------------------------------
con_applied <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "applied_systems", timeout = 10, database = "Harris_11292021")

# Load tables -------------------------------------------------------------
policy_master <- tbl(con_applied, in_schema("dbo", "Applicant"))
```

Comment: Kudos for submitting the answer to your own question! This is the way :-)